# Adding rows from select statement to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to add rows to a `DataGridView` where the row data comes from a *select* statement. Here is my code so far:

```
ArrayList stock_idArray =  GetStockID_line_item(purchase_id);
foreach (int stock_id in stock_idArray)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StockDetails.stock_item WHERE stock_id=@stock_id", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock_id", stock_id);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    con.Open();
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "ItemDetails");
    con.Close();
    //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "ItemDetails";
}
```

However its not working as it is showing only 1 row instead of all rows. I want to retrieve rows for multiple `stock_id` and then put them in a single `DataGridView`.

Comment: Well? What is your question?

Comment: You can use a `BindingSource` as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` and  the `DataSet` as `DataSource` of the `BindingSource`.

Comment: @user2946329 Sorry i missed some parts in question , please read again

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry  the question was incomplete kindly read the question again

Comment: after your foreach loop, you need to bind the data to the datagrid. So after the loop, try adding a dataGridView1.DataBind(); call.

Comment: Can you check if the dataset is not null?

Comment: @user2650277, you create a new `DataSet ds` for each `stock_id` and bind  grid to the last dataset. try initialize `ds` once before loop: `DataSet ds = new DataSet(); foreach(...) {...} dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;` . (and also set datasource after loop)

Comment: @ASh You were absolutely right....kindly post your comment as an answer so that i can accept:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you create a new `DataSet ds` for each `stock_id` and bind grid to `ds` on each iteration. when all operations are completed, the grid is bound to the last dataset.

try initialize `ds` once before loop and also set `DataSource` after loop:

```
ArrayList stock_idArray =  GetStockID_line_item(purchase_id);
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
foreach (int stock_id in stock_idArray)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM StockDetails.stock_item WHERE stock_id=@stock_id", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock_id", stock_id);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    con.Open();
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "ItemDetails");
    con.Close();
} 
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "ItemDetails";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Data is in a Table called `ItemDetails`. So you should Bind to `DataTable` not `DataSet`:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Or:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ItemDetails"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add your data to your grid using code from your statement within a foreach loop using

```
dataGridVew.Rows.Add();
```

That way you can control what you want to show and whatnot.im strongly against bindings because of that.u can also add an object of your data type to a hidden column of the same row for future references if youre relying on oo programming .